# How do I perform a clustering algorithm (like DBSCAN) in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I need to cluster some data in Snowflake using DBSCAN. I created a UDF but the results won't match with a local run, so I ran an UDF that just creates a list with the row number that is being processed and it results in a list that has repeated values and its max value is much smaller than the number of rows in my table. (The expected result was unique values up to the number of rows)
Can this be a parallelization issue?
If so, is there a way to cluster data using DBSCAN in Snowflake?

Thanks!

EDIT -> code example:

```py
@funcs.pandas_udf(name='DBSCAN_TEST', is_permanent=True,
                stage_location='@UDF', replace=True,
                packages=['scikit-learn==1.0.2', 'pandas', 'numpy'])
def DBSCAN_TEST(data_x: types.PandasDataFrame[float, float]) -> types.PandasSeries[float]:
    data_x.columns = [features]
    DBSCAN_cluster = DBSCAN(eps=2.5, min_samples=4)
    DBSCAN_cluster.fit(data_x)
    return resul
```

As input data I used [this](https://reneshbedre.github.io/assets/posts/tsne/tsne_scores.csv)
to test DBSCAN.

If I run that locally (using the exact same code inside the UDF) I end up with 24 clusters and that is the expected result. But if I use the UDF it scales up to 71.

I've tried changing the input types to string, as a coworker suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: I posted an answer that had to do with physical clustering, but see that you're looking to product a clustered result of data (mutually exclusive of the physical data layout).  Please post your code, and some sample data / expected results so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

The only clustering option in Snowflake is a clustering key, and general rule of thumb is that this isn't something typically needed until you eclipse a TB of data in a table and/or the auto clustering proves to be deficient in performance.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html